# Is there a way to statically link the glib2 library？

Tags: c++, glib

Since the production device does not have a glib2 runtime environment, I need to statically link to glib2. I tried to compile and link in the following ways, but it still links libglib-2.0.so.0. I am sure that libglib-2.0.a exists on my device.

```
#include <glib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *test;
    test = g_new0(char,1);
    g_free(test);

    return 0;
}
```

i tried build it by

```
gcc `pkg-config --static --libs --cflags glib-2.0` main.c -o test
ldd test
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe9dbc8000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2ee333f000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2ee31fb000)
        libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f2ee3183000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2ee3162000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2ee2f93000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2ee3492000)
```

Comment: interesting. What's the output of `pkg-config --static --libs --cflags glib-2.0`?

Comment: maybe try using a project manager like cmake. then you do not have to go through the hassle of writing g++ commands yourself

Comment: @Marcus Müller
    `[root@fedora src]# pkg-config --static --libs --cflags glib-2.0
    -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/sysprof-4 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -pthread -lm -lpcre -lsysprof-capture-4 -pthread`

Answer (score 0):

The flags that `pkg-config --static` gives you are library flags suited for a program that will ultimately be statically linked. Now, it's not `pkg-config`'s job to configure *your* build, just to give you the flags your libraries need.

So, you need to add `-s` to your `gcc` command yourself.